# parse error in the code but can't spot the error

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Char

shift :: Int -> Char -> Char
shift n c | isLower c = int2let((let2int c + n) `mod` 26)
          | otherwise = c

let2int :: Char -> Int
let2int c = ord c - ord `a`

int2let :: Int -> Char
int2let n = chr(ord `a` + n)
```

This is the code for the Caesar cipher where I have experienced a problem in parse error with the line `int2let :: Int -> Char`. I'm not sure why it's wrong.

Comment: `ord 'a'` should have single quotes, not backticks. Backticks are used to make a function into an infix operator, so if you include something in backticks the parser expects an identifier afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have pointed this out in the comments but I thought I'd explain a little more.

The Haskell interpreter is useful here. Let's try and see what the type of 
`a` is.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t `a`

<interactive>:1:1: error: parse error on input ‘`’
```

That's not good... So let's try single and double quotes

```
Prelude> :t 'a'
'a' :: Char
Prelude> :t "a"
"a" :: [Char]
```

Thus,

```
let2int :: Char -> Int
let2int c = ord c - ord `a`

int2let :: Int -> Char
int2let n = chr(ord `a` + n)
```

Should be

```
let2int :: Char -> Int
let2int c = ord c - ord 'a'

int2let :: Int -> Char
int2let n = chr(ord 'a' + n)
```

For reference, here's some documentation on the [infix operator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator)